# FBSDKAccestoken iOS always return a invalid access token after login again

Tags: ios, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I have an issue when logging in with Facebook in my iOS app. Everything works ok until I change my Facebook account password.  After that, I open my app and it requires that I login again. But after I re-enter my new password and login succeeds, I get the new access token with this call `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString` and discover that access token is invalid.

I tried to debug with the Facebook Debug tool and I always get this result:

> Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored
>   session. This may be because the user changed the password since the
>   time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for
>   security reasons.

Please help me! :( I need to send this access token to my server so my server can get the user info. But after users change their Facebook account password, the token will become invalid and then my server code doesn't work.

Comment: I tested this scenario and was able to get back the new access token which was valid while the older one was invalidated. Make sure you are not  using the older access token and if you are placing it in a variable, replace it with the new one once the user logs in again.

Comment: Hi Bangdel, thanks for your reply. But i dont know how to get the new accesstoken, when i need to get accesstoken string, i always call the method [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString];

Comment: It depends on whether you are using the Login button or custom login flow. If you are using the Login button then you can call the method you mentioned in the delegate method `loginButton:didCompleteWithResult`. If it is a custom flow then you can call the method in `logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler` if there are no errors.